# Internet connection on ubuntu 18.04 is way slower than on windows 10

Tags: networking, 18.04

On windows 10 the internet connection is 80mbps and on ubuntu it is 15/20mbps.
I already searched solutions, but I didn't find anything that works for me.
output of sudo lshw:

```
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlo1
             version: 10
             serial: b4:69:21:11:27:72
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-37-generic firmware=43.95eb4e97.0 ip=192.168.1.98 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: irq:16 memory:a441c000-a441ffff
```

Comment: is your router 802.11n protocol capable ?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest couple of fixes with my reasons.

**First fix**

iwlwifi drivers are pretty bad in handling 802.11n protocol. Only newer routers can handle this protocol anyways. So your first step will be to disable the 802.11n and check your internet speed.

To disable:

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

If this helps you need to make the changes permanent. If not just reboot and you will revert to the old settings.

To make it permanent:

`sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

`reboot`

**Second Fix**

Power management could be incorrectly restricting the power to your network card.

Run: `sudo iwconfig`

This will show you the name of your device.

Now Run: `sudo iwconfig <device name> power off`

`reboot`